# Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'y'

Tags: regex, safari, flags, polyfills

Safari v9 doesn't support the sticky flag 'y'

Example (from MDN):

```
var str1 = 'table football';
var regex1 = new RegExp('foo','y');

regex1.lastIndex = 6;

console.log(regex1.sticky);
// expected output: true

console.log(regex1.test(str1));
// expected output: true

console.log(regex1.test(str1));
// expected output: false
```

Is there any polyfill or any workaround to add the right support to that browser or to those browsers that still don't support it natively?

Comment: I have tryed already babel-polyfill https://jsfiddle.net/zrz1cjyo/ without any success

Comment: what about using `'^(?:foo)+'` instead

Comment: this is out of my control when this is used from a third party library, I have notified to them the lack of support for older browsers... https://github.com/projectfluent/fluent.js/issues/129